# Problema na publicação shinyapp

Tags: r, shiny

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O app(ui+server) roda normalmente mas na hora de publicar no http://www.shinyapps.io/ esta dando o erro da imagem como proceder para resolver.
Se necessario posso postar os códigos.

Comment: tenta tirar os acentos do script e ver se vai

Comment: VALEU CARA DEU CERTO

Comment: Isso é problema de encoding... Talvez salvando o arq com outro enc funcione.

Comment: @Gabriel Mizuno já que deu certo coloque a resposta e feche a pergunta.

Comment: Sou novo no Stack overflow e não sei mexer muito nele,como faço para "fechar a pergunta"?